# Hide form tabs for specific user groups

Tags: security, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

There is requirement to hide certain tabs for certain user groups on a form. Thing is, hiding all the fields in the tab does not seem to work. Any ideas are appreciated. Working with AX 2009.

Comment: I ended up creating security keys for each permission on tab I needed, then assigned permissions to those keys in respective user groups.

Comment: +1 for using the right approach. When you have gained enough reputation, you can answer your own question.

Comment: +1 for the importance of the goal to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone needed an answer to this with visuals:
In AX you can assign a security key to a tab via the properties sheet:

[image: Security key property]
Then you can either make use of existing security keys or create your own in order to control user visibility by assigning only the users you want to see the tab to have access to that key.