# dynamics ax 2009 form control security permissions

Tags: forms, security, permissions, controls, dynamics-ax-2009

The documentation says, you can control permissions at a form control level. If you wanted a group of users to not have permissions on the sales order details form for certain controls, how would you go about doing it?

Comment: Take a look at [Hide form tabs for specific user groups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18761393/hide-form-tabs-for-specific-user-groups), sounds very similar.

Comment: It is the same as the answer for the question that @FH-Inway linked. Set the SecurityKey property on the form controls.

Answer (score 0):

There's a property in form controls called "Security Key", you can create or just use one that already exists.
If you choose to create, you must link a user group to this Security Key... and if you create the user group, you must link users to this group.

If you don't link any user group to this Security Key, only admins will see.

Or else, you can do something like this in the init method of the form: (I don't recommend)

```
if(curuserid() == "RT.")
{
    formcontrol.visible(true);
}
```